# How to create a Horizontal Progress indicator (showing in image )

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar

How to create a Horizontal Progress indicator (showing in image ) such that it is in xml and we can set a a percentage value for example if we set value to 50 then it is half fill[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the progress in XML

```
 <ProgressBar
  android:id="@+id/progressBar"
  style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:progress="20"/>
```

And via JAVA

```
 ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
 progressBar.setProgress(50);
```